# NSSM windows service still running after shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, nssm

I have a .net service installed and launched by NSSM, sometimes the service can shutdown with an emergency code, it completely stops any actions, but status still remains "Running". If I install and launch service via SC, service stops successfully (status changed to "Stopped"), so seems NSSM can't catch shutdown from inside of service by some reason. Btw, default value of AppExit key not set to "Ignore".

Comment: We're going to need more information about your service. How is its entry point defined? Which framework are you in? Are you overriding OnStop() ?

Comment: 4.7.2 framework, service inherited from ServiceBase and uses it's method Stop().